# JAVA questissn regarding methods/classes

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor, symbols

I am somewhat new to JAVA.  I've been working with it in college, but I have to admit, my instructor is of absolutely no help.  She hardly knows JAVA herself, but that is another issue all in itself.  I've been confused as to how methods and classes work.  I'm creating this program that uses two files, one "main" file, and a "test" file.  I can't seem to get the "main" file correct, as the compiler keeps telling me that it cannot find the symbols, even though they are.  In the "test" file, I can't seem to get the compiler to recognize the methods from the "main" file.  I have made sure that the files are in the same folder.  I want to combine them into one file for simplicity, but I will lose points.  I've included my code so far.  I'm not looking for a "fix-it" solution, I just want to figure out why it's not working.  ANY help is appreciated, since my instructor isn't of much assistance  Thank you kindly!

---

MAIN FILE:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Fruit1 {
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String color;
        String taste;
    }

    public Fruit1() {
        // generic constructor

        color = "red";
        taste = "yum";

    }

    public Fruit1(String aColor, String aTaste) {
        // constructor with parameters
        color = aColor;
        taste = aTaste;
    }

    public Fruit1(String bColor, String bTaste) {

        color = bColor;
        taste = bTaste;
    }

    String getTaste() {
        return taste;
    }

    String getColor() {
        // Accessor method
        return color;
    }
}
```

---

TEST FILE:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Fruit1Test {

    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Fruit1 a = new Fruit1("pinkish-red", "sweet-tart");
        Fruit1 l = new Fruit1("yellow", "tart/sour");

        a.taste();
        a.color();
        l.taste();
        l.color();

        System.out.println("Your apple is " + a.color + "in color and has a " + a.taste + " taste. ");
        System.out.println("Your lemon is " + l.color + "in color and has a " + l.taste + " taste. ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that your file names are `Fruit1.java` and `Fruit1Test.java`??

Comment: Please copy the command lines and errors ( Could you try using an IDE? It helps you to focus on the learning side.)  Since you are learning mode, it helps to read more about 'junit' - it helps to improve testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.taste();` will try to find method `taste();` in your main file i.e. in `Fruit1.java` file. However as same is not found, it will throw error at compile time only that Method `taste()` is not found...

All below 4 statements will **FAIL** as those are not present...

```
a.taste();
a.color();
l.taste();
l.color();
```

As you are creating object of class by using below statement, already values to taste and color by use of constructor `public Fruit1(String aColor, String aTaste){`.

`Fruit1 a = new Fruit1("pinkish-red", "sweet-tart");`

I believe you now want to print the values of color and taste. To print those use getter methods that you have (getColor() & getTaste())

```
System.out.println("Your apple is " + a.getColor() + " in color and has a " + a.getTaste() + " taste. ");

System.out.println("Your Lemon is " + l.getColor() + " in color and has a " + l.getTaste() + " taste. ");
```

### Note

You don't need to write `public Fruit1(String bColor, String bTaste){` again as you have already defined above that....

Also your below statement should be before constructor and out of psvm

```
String color;
String taste;
```

Let me know if you are unclear...

### Good Luck

Comment: Thank you!  That makes complete sense! Although, I remember having to call the attributes from the method in a program I did that was similar.  Why would it not be able to find it?  I read below about how it's because the main file wasn't compiling, which is very possible.  However, when the main file was compiling, it still couldn't access it.  Is that because I was trying to access the wrong method?

Comment: there was error at `a.taste();` hence your `System.out.println("Your apple is " + a.color + "in c` will not get printed... is that you want?

Answer (score 1):

You never declare the fields `color` or `taste` for the object `Fruit1`. Instead, you created the variables in the `main` method.

I suggest you read some [basic tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) on Java to get the hang of things. (Oracle also provides more [advanced tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).)

Comment: I'm currently working through Head First JAVA as I'm enrolled in my JAVA II class.  I'm just used to everything being in the main, and the instructor I have now didn't really explain why everything shouldn't be.  I've read the tutorials, but honestly, it can be overwhelming, especially if you don't know why you're doing something wrong.  This is my first real experience with programming, aside from a SQL class, so it's a bit difficult to grasp the concepts sometimes.  I'll look at the tutorials again, though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed in Fruit1, you are declaring the member variables in function main(). From the looks of it, Fruit1Test should have a main() fxn but Fruit1 should not. Take out those member variables out of main() and get rid of main() in Fruit1 (put it under the 'console' variable).

I also noticed that you have 2 constructors that both take in Strings. The compiler will probably complain about that too. I don't have a compiler in front of me but that's what I can tell just from looking.

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem, it seems you're misunderstanding how to declare instance fields. You're creating them inside the `main` function, when you should create them directly inside the class.

For your second problem, see Fahim Parkar's comment, if it applies to your case. BTW it's a good practice to always have only one class/interface/enum per file, and have the file with the same name of the class (this second part may be mandatory in Java, I don't remember for sure - it applies to `public` classes, but I dunno if it also applies for "default, package protected" ones).

If they're named correctly, OTOH, maybe the error is because your "main" file didn't compile, so the "test" one didn't find it...

P.S. I just noticed you have two constructors with the same signature (number of parameters and same parameter types). You must remove one.

Comment: Hello!  My instructor is making us put two constructors in, she wants us to "overload," even though it's not necessary for the program.  Is there any way around this?  It seems like there isn't, because I'll just continue to get errors.

Comment: If you have one constructor without parameter, and other with, you're already overloading. You could also have constructors with the same number of parameters, but of different types, but it doesn't always make sense. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) for more info